# Customize Jupyter background error color in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, oh-my-zsh

I have problems with vs-code Jupyter Notebook colors  ( after install ohmyzsh default theme ) .. where can I change the color values ​​to remove this annoying yellow background?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

I find a solution.
To find all possible vs-code color customization ran:

press F1 then write
`Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings`

then press F1 -> setting.json

on setting json add

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.ansiYellow": "#8400ffe1",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @Marco idea, press F1: `Preferences: Open workspace settings (Json)`

add this line to that json, Ctrl + S to save

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.ansiYellow": "#8400ffe1",
}
```

The background would turn to purple

[image]